# Is there a delay between calling Thread.Start and its code being run?

Tags: .net, multithreading, thread-safety

I was looking at the [example for Thread.Join in MS' docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.thread.join?view=netframework-4.7.2) (code copied below).

I was initially unsure that this code is correct because it seemed that `thread1` would start first, and would try to access the state of `thread2` before it was created.
And when I tried it on one online compiler, I did indeed get an exception. But on another, it worked fine and I saw sometimes `thread2` ran first.

So is this sample code wrong and are there any rules on when a thread will start, or how long it can take? Is this all handled via the messaging queue 
meaning that in theory neither thread should actually start (WinAPI `CreateThread`) until `Main()` relinquishes control?

```
using System;
using System.Threading;

public class Example
{
   static Thread thread1, thread2;

   public static void Main()
   {
      thread1 = new Thread(ThreadProc);
      thread1.Name = "Thread1";
      thread1.Start();

      thread2 = new Thread(ThreadProc);
      thread2.Name = "Thread2";
      thread2.Start();   
   }

   private static void ThreadProc()
   {
      Console.WriteLine("\nCurrent thread: {0}", Thread.CurrentThread.Name);
      if (Thread.CurrentThread.Name == "Thread1" && 
          thread2.ThreadState != ThreadState.Unstarted)
         thread2.Join();

      Thread.Sleep(4000);
      Console.WriteLine("\nCurrent thread: {0}", Thread.CurrentThread.Name);
      Console.WriteLine("Thread1: {0}", thread1.ThreadState);
      Console.WriteLine("Thread2: {0}\n", thread2.ThreadState);
   }
}
// The example displays output like the following:
//       Current thread: Thread1
//       
//       Current thread: Thread2
//       
//       Current thread: Thread2
//       Thread1: WaitSleepJoin
//       Thread2: Running
//       
//       
//       Current thread: Thread1
//       Thread1: Running
//       Thread2: Stopped
```

Comment: A different approach to making thread1 wait until thread2 is done, would be to communicate between the two with a [ManualResetEvent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.waithandle.waitone?view=netframework-4.8).  As an added benefit, you could "spin" in a loop with a specified interval, either shorter if you want to do something else in thread1 while it's "waiting" for thread2, or longer if you just need a maximum timeout.

Answer (score 2):

MSDN samples *aren't production code*. They're there to illustrate a concept, not show how to implement it properly. Some aren't even good at illustrating concepts. In general, you shouldn't treat MSDN samples as something to put in *your* code, ever.

There is no way to know in which order the two threads are going to execute `ThreadProc`. The sample has a race condition - `thread2` can be null by the time the first thread tries to access it, or the thread might not be ready to be joined yet (and you lose all synchronization between `thread1` and `thread2`).

In short, *the code is wrong*. It's especially wrong because *it might appear to work most of the time*. This is pretty common in multi-threaded code, and something you need to be very wary of. You need to be absolutely sure you're doing the right thing, rather than relying on the common pattern of "make a change, try running the code, works? done".

If you wanted the minimal possible changes to `ThreadProc` to make this code thread-safe, without redesigning the whole thing, you would want something like this:

```
Console.WriteLine("\nCurrent thread: {0}", Thread.CurrentThread.Name);
if (Thread.CurrentThread.Name == "Thread1")
{
  while (thread2 == null || thread2.ThreadState == ThreadState.Unstarted)
    Thread.Sleep(100);

  thread2.Join();
}

Thread.Sleep(4000);
Console.WriteLine("\nCurrent thread: {0}", Thread.CurrentThread.Name);
Console.WriteLine("Thread1: {0}", thread1.ThreadState);
Console.WriteLine("Thread2: {0}\n", thread2.ThreadState);
```

This still isn't what I'd call production-ready, but it makes the code work, in C#, on a x86 CPU, on a standards-compliant .NET runtime implementation. It will ensure `thread1`'s thread proc waits for `thread2`'s to finish, but it also introduces the possibility of `thread1` to be stuck indefinitely if `thread2` doesn't ever start for some reason (better practice would be to have a timeout on the spinning). It's stupid and simple, and definitely a bad way to do multi-threading and synchronization, but it's thread-safe.

Comment: Thanks. Of course I don't expect example code to be production ready but I would expect it to _work_. Sample code that leaves you more confused is not worth much and I'd expect them to spot this if someone like me did. Is it possible to notify them?

Comment: @Mr.Boy It used to be. There probably were comments on the article in the old MSDN. You could use MS Connect to report the issue, and they usually got fixed eventually. These days, you should be able to edit the page directly, but I have no idea how that works; the whole documentation is on GitHub, so maybe you're supposed to make the change and create a pull request? There's also issues there, and they seem to be resolved.

Comment: @Mr.Boy I think there was also a note that you shouldn't really use `Join` unless you can't avoid it; unless you have a very good reason, you should use other synchronisation options (like semaphores, events, tasks...).